# Python CSV get a value from a cell by value from previous columns

Tags: python, list, csv

Can I find a value from Z column if I have two known values from X and Y?

| X; | Y; | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A; | 1; | syfgusj |
| A; | 2; | adaddsfd |
| B; | 1; | adsghfjgftrds |
| B; | 2m; | adergtw |
| C; | 1; | adergtw |
| C; | 2; | addfgftre |

Values in Y column are string type.

I should find value in Z column by known values from columns X and Y.
I converted CSV to list of lists, but can`t even imagine how to make next step.

Comment: What do you think the "next step" would be?  Is there *any* aspect of this problem you can solve?

Comment: Do you mean that  `A; 1;` will always point to `syfgusj` ?

Comment: @balderman, yes, other rows makes the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Considering values are unique, I would store the csv on a pandas dataframe, and then iterate over every row on the dataframe. If column 1 value and column 2 values are the ones you know, then return the z value from that exact row.

That should do it, tell me if u need further help!

Comment: I have never worked with pandas before, can you help with it?

Comment: Here you have the documentation, you can look up anything there: [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/). You can read a csv and parse it into a dataframe, to do that see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-read-csv-using-pandas-read_csv/)